# How do I log out/disconnect from SSH after starting a process with output to keep it running?

Tags: ssh, scripting

I ran a script from the command line today (php, not sure that matters) which has output I wanted to watch but I had to go home before it finished and I couldn't figure out how to exit without killing the script. Normally I just close the laptop (hibernate) but it doesn't appear the script finished.

Is there some keyboard combination I can hit to exit the terminal and leave the script running? It prints a log file too so I can just check it later.

Answer (score 2):

The most straightforward method to have your scripts continue after you close out of a shell session is to use a terminal multiplexer program.  A terminal multiplexer will allow you to run multiple shell sessions concurrently without being actively connected to each one, even after you disconnect (detach) from them.  The 2 most popular ones are `screen` and `tmux`.

I personally use `screen` and it works extremely well for me.  You start a `screen` session, start your program/script, disconnect(detach), then reconnect to the detached session later on to see how things went.

To install:

```
sudo apt-get install screen
```

To start a session:

```
screen
```

To disconnect (detach) from the session:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> then <kbd>d</kbd>

To list running sessions:

```
screen -ls
```

To reconnect to a detached session, use the output from `screen -ls`

```
screen -r [pid.tty.host]
```

These are just the basics to get you going, but like always, `man screen` has much more info

Comment: `screen` is awesome; [tmux](http://tmux.sourceforge.net/) may be more useful, as it's more customizable.

Comment: Note that `byobu` is not a “third” choice, it's more like a wrapper; it needs either `screen` or `tmux` to run (it was originally based on `screen`) and extends display and features.

Comment: @Qeole wasn't aware of that, will update.  Thanks